# My javascript alert dialog box appears empty. What is the reason?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The result of alert dialog comes up empty. I am not able to access the parent of parent node

```js
var bt = document.getElementById("btn1");
bt.onclick = function() {
  alert(bt.parentNode.parentNode.className);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="template">
      <div class="img "> <img src="images/demo/hotel1.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="hname animated slideInRight">
        <h2>Golden Tulip <span id="city">Lucknow</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="address animated slideInLeft animated slideInLeft"> <span id="city"><b>Lucknow,<b></span> 2km to city centre. <button id="btn1">View Deal</button> </div>
      <div class="rating"> 5 star </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using a proper IDE would let you easily realize you have a syntax error in your html.

Comment: Yes it will or a code editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to close the `b` tag here: `<b>Lucknow,<b>`

This is probably causing the browser to correct for that incorrect structure by closing that tag. As a result, an additional `b` element is added as a parent to the button's hierarchy. The resultant structure is:

```
<b>
    <b> 
        2km to city centre. 
        <button id="btn1">View Deal</button> 
    </b>
</b>
```

When you close that `b` tag, the result is fine:

```js
var bt = document.getElementById("btn1");
bt.onclick = function() {
  alert(bt.parentNode.parentNode.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="template">
    <div class="img "> <img src="images/demo/hotel1.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="hname animated slideInRight">
      <h2>Golden Tulip <span id="city">Lucknow</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="address animated slideInLeft animated slideInLeft"> <span id="city"><b>Lucknow,</b></span> 2km to city centre. <button id="btn1">View Deal</button> </div>
    <div class="rating"> 5 star </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--THE RESULT OF ALERT DIALOG COMES EMPTY.I AM NOT ABLE TO ACCESS THE PARENT OF PARENT NODE-->
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for me being silly

Comment: @user5573523 Don't worry. It is often hard to predict that browsers can *autocorrect* HTML syntax rather than reporting them as errors.